# Predições a partir de Validação Cruzada

Tags: python, regressão, sklearn

Eu estou trabalhando com um problema de regressão. Eu construi um Multilayerperceptron
(MLP) usando o Scikit-learn. Eu fiz duas predições...uma usando o MPL usando 70% dos
dados para treinamento e 30% para validação. Calculando o Erro Médio Quadrático (EMQ)
do valor gerado pelo MLP e pela base de validação eu cheguei a um EMQ de 0.583 (variável erro)
Eu tentei pegar o mesmo MLP e fazer uma predição usando validação cruzada com o 'cross_val_predict'
e imaginava q o EMQ seria menor que o EMQ do MLP porém, o valor do EMQ (errocv) deu 3.584.
Eu fiz alguma coisa errada no meu código, na parte da validação cruzada, ou é normal assim mesmo?

```
#Importando os Módulos
import pandas as pd
import keras
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate 
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_predict
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

#Importando o Dataset
base = pd.read_excel('Aval_ASF_Alt_Elip.xlsx')#Dataset

#Definição das Variaveis  x e y
x = base.iloc[:, 6:7].values
y = base.iloc[:, 5:6].values

#Dividindo os dados em treinamento em teste
X_treinamento, X_teste, y_treinamento, y_teste = train_test_split(x,y, 
                                                                  test_size=0.30,random_state=0)

#Criando o MLP
model = MLPRegressor(hidden_layer_sizes=(10,10,10,10,10,10,10),activation='identity',
                     solver='adam',learning_rate='constant',batch_size='auto', 
                     max_iter=1000,verbose=False,random_state=0)

#Treinando o MLP
model.fit(X_treinamento, y_treinamento.ravel())

#Geração das Predições do MLP 
ypred_skl = model.predict(y_teste)
ypred_skl = ypred_skl.reshape(-1,1)

#Calculo do Erro do MLP
erro = np.round(np.sqrt(np.mean((y_teste-ypred_skl)**2)),3)

#Validação Cruzada
ypredcv = cross_val_predict(model, x, y.ravel(), cv=15, verbose=0)
ypredcv = ypredcv.reshape(-1,1)

#Calculo do Erro da Validação Cruzada
errocv = np.round(np.sqrt(np.mean((y-ypredcv)**2)),3)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Grato pela atenção.

Comment: Vc fez a validação do seu modelo usando ```test_size = 0.30```, ou seja, 30% do seu dataset será utilizado para teste, enquanto que na validação cruzada vc utilizou "15-fold validation", que divide seu dataset em 15 grupos de tamanho igual para realizar a validação cruzada. Com isso, vc tem tamanho de treino/teste diferentes para a validação simples e para a validação cruzada. Isso pode ter ocasionado o problema no erro. Recomendo o ```sklearn.metrics``` para calcular suas métricas de validação.

Comment: Obrigado. Vou fazer isso.